# Check if code exist in database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, mysqli

I want to ask what's wrong with my code. I want to make a website where you type code in input and ajax sends request php file and there mysqli query checks if code exist in database and return result. Here is my Php file, ajax reguest and html input code.

Everything with database is okay, because I have table named 'user' and there is kodas named 'testas', so it's not that kind fault.

Everytime php file returns to ajax '0' because I see it from console.log

PHP

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost' , 'username', 'password', 'database');
    if ($mysqli->connect_error){
        echo 2;
    }

    $kodas = $_POST["input-text"];

    $statement = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT kodas FROM user WHERE kodas = ?");
    $statement->bind_param('s', $kodas);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->bind_result($kodas);
    if($statement->fetch()){
        echo 1;
    }else{
        echo 0;
    }

?>
```

Ajax request :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#input-button').on('click', function(){
       var kodas = document.getElementById("input-text").value;
       jQuery.ajax({                
           url: "link to file.php", 
           type: 'POST',
           data : { issiusta: kodas },  
           success: function(array) {
            console.log(array);
            if(array == 1){
                  alert("Code exist!");
            }else if(array ==2) {
                  alert("Can't Connect to Database");
            } else {
                  alert("Error");
            }
           }
       }); 
    }); 
});
```

HTML

```
<input id="input-text" name="input-text" type="text" value="Slaptas Kodas" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Slaptas Kodas';}"onfocus="if (this.value == 'Slaptas Kodas') {this.value = '';}"/>
  <input id="input-button" type="submit" value="Prisijungti" />
```

Comment: look at your developer console, use php's error reporting and check for errors on the query.

Comment: Sorry, I'm fresh, how could I do that?

Comment: `issiusta` !== `input-text`

Comment: ...and hard to say what the HTML looks like also. Edit: oh, that was just added, least "some" of it.

Comment: You should be using `$kodas = $_POST["issiusta"];`, just as @jeroen pointed out.

Comment: Thank you very much @jeroen!

Comment: You're welcome! Also note that you should `exit;` after you echo your return codes as you will never receive `2`; it will probably be followed by error messages.